# Cost-effective method of traveling from Luton Airport to Wembley, London

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, london, taxis, ltn

I'm visiting London with my friends, 6 people total. We're coming with Wizzair to Luton Airport.

At first we were going to take a train from Luton Airport Parkway (I was told it's about 15 GBP), so total cost would be about 90.

Next thing I thought of was taking a taxi to Wembley where we have accomodation to leave the luggage and then continue with the tube to central London. I called one of the cheap taxi companies for the quote and they told us the price is 90 GBP. When asked why is that, because their price starts at 45 GBP from Luton, they answered that they count 15 GBP per person.

Is this normal? I feel like we are getting robbed with this price, but I don't know, maybe it's OK here. When looking for other offers, I've seen that there is Addison Lee officialy operating from Luton airport. And with all that negative comments I can see about them - I don't think it's worth risking.

Another idea I have is to split into two groups - first in a cab will go to Wembley with all the luggage, and second group will go by train straight to St. Pancreas station so we'll meet afterwards. Maybe this would cost less?

I'd be grateful for Your help!

Comment: What date and time does your flight arrive?

Comment: Thursday, 7:35 AM

Comment: This coming Thursday?

Comment: Why, does it matter? Are you going to pick us up, @gparyani ? ;)

Comment: No, I'm searching it up. Sometimes companies reduce prices if you book far in advance, so I just want to know that so I can get an accurate price estimate. Also, it would be useful for me to know how much luggage you're carrying.

Comment: Just the standard Wizzair cabin luggage, up to 10kg each. I was searching too, Twelve states 71 GBP for the trip (6 people) and UberXL is about 80

Comment: You are not being robbed if a price is quoted to you in advance because you are still free to shop around. If you were quoted 45 and then charged 90 on the day that would be quite different.

Comment: Small tip, if you want to use London public transport, it is very handy to have a contactless card, otherwise you need to buy an Oystercard or pay a lot extra for the underground and can not use the buses.

Comment: @user16259 Being robbed (not literally of course) isn't always about price known upfront... For example - 70cl bottle of vodka in Norway costs about 30 euro. It's acceptable price. The same price for the same bottle of vodka in Poland would be a total ripoff. And the prices are known upfront. Everything depends on the usual local price and when arriving to foreign country it isn't obvious how much should something cost.

Comment: @Willeke we want to make Oystercards ASAP to benefit daily capping

Comment: You also get the daily capping on your contactless bank cards, without having money bound into a separate card. (You can get the money from the oystercard at the end of the visit but is an extra job.)

Comment: @Willeke only few of us have contactless cards. Also I am not sure about currency conversion when using contactless card...

Comment: For me any use of my (Dutch) bank card cost a percentage, but it works out the same as getting 100 pound at a time from the ATM. It is worth checking what you pay, if you are willing to trust your card on the system.

Comment: Oyster cards hold their value for a long time.  We reused our 2007 cards on our 2015 visit, and a check last week on the TFL site revealed the few pounds remaining on the cards are still there.  You don't need to go to London that often to justify having Oyster cards.

Comment: @Willeke Your Oyster deposit is refunded when you return it.

Answer (score 7):

You can buy bus tickets from Luton to Central London on https://easybus.com (you don't need to fly with a specific airline).
The nominal price to Paddington (National line) is 10 GBP, but you can buy (in advance, online) discounted tickets starting from 2 GBP for some schedule. There is the green line with a stop at brent cross, 5 miles from wenbley.

You need to add the tube/bus price, of course, and it won't be particularly fast.

Answer (score 3):

We ended up calling UberXL and paid 62 GBP for a trip to Wembley, arriving at the doors of our apartment :) Estimated price was 57-72 GBP so I guess it was good decision.